my chat user are not connecting each other
i am building a a private chat and calls both voice and video that preach privacy, with full privacy end to end, no message stored or saved to the backend, and every message is encrypted, so no one could breach it, every user has been given the power to thier own chat, now no matter what i do the chat isnt working i feel like my my consumer.py is not well written, i want user to chat and video call each other, but they are not chatting for example a user is not connecting with each other, its like they are not in a room together
import json
import logging
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from chat.models import UserProfile

 # Set up the logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

 class SecureChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

  async def connect(self):
      self.user = self.scope['user']
      self.friend_username = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs'] 
      ['username']

    if not self.user.is_authenticated:
        await self.close()
        return

    if not self.friend_username or not isinstance(self.friend_username, str):
        logger.error("Friend username is missing or invalid during WebSocket connection.")
        await self.close()
        return

    try:
        # Create a shared room name between both users for proper communication
        self.room_name = f"chat_{'_'.join(sorted([self.user.username, self.friend_username]))}"
        
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.update_user_status(online=True)
        await self.accept()
        logger.info(f"WebSocket connection established for user {self.user.username} in room {self.room_name}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error during WebSocket connection: {e}")
        await self.close()

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_name, self.channel_name)
    await self.update_user_status(online=False)
    logger.info(f"WebSocket disconnected for user {self.user.username}")

async def receive(self, text_data):
    """
    Handle incoming WebSocket messages. Distinguish between message events, WebRTC events, and other types.
    """
    try:
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        message_type = data.get('type')
        logger.info(f"Received message of type '{message_type}' from {self.user.username}")
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        logger.error(f"Error parsing message data: {e}")
        await self.send_error("Invalid JSON format.")
        return

    if message_type == 'message':
        await self.handle_message_event(data)
    elif message_type in ['call_offer', 'call_answer', 'ice_candidate']:
        await self.handle_webrtc_event(data)
    elif message_type == 'public_key':
        await self.handle_key_exchange(data)
    elif message_type == 'user_status':
        await self.handle_user_status(data)
    else:
        logger.warning(f"Unknown message type received: {message_type}")
        await self.send_error("Unknown message type.")

async def handle_message_event(self, data):
    """
    Handle secure chat message events between two users using end-to-end encryption.
    """
    message = data.get('message')
    recipient_username = data.get('to')

    if message and recipient_username:
        logger.info(f"Forwarding encrypted message from {self.user.username} to {recipient_username}")
        await self.forward_message(recipient_username, message, data.get('iv'))

async def forward_message(self, recipient_username, message, iv):
    """
    Forward an encrypted message to the specified recipient.
    """
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        f"chat_{'_'.join(sorted([self.user.username, recipient_username]))}",
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': message,
            'iv': iv,
            'sender': self.user.username
        }
    )

async def chat_message(self, event):
    """
    Deliver the chat message to the WebSocket client.
    """
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type': 'message',
        'message': event['message'],
        'iv': event['iv'],
        'sender': event['sender']
    }))

async def handle_webrtc_event(self, data):
    """
    Handle WebRTC signaling for peer-to-peer voice and video calls.
    """
    recipient_username = data.get('to')
    event_type = data['type']
    event_data = data['data']

    if recipient_username:
        await self.forward_webrtc_signal(recipient_username, event_type, event_data)

async def forward_webrtc_signal(self, recipient_username, signal_type, data):
    """
    Forward WebRTC signaling data to the specified recipient.
    """
    if not recipient_username:
        logger.error("Recipient username is missing for WebRTC signal.")
        return

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        f"chat_{'_'.join(sorted([self.user.username, recipient_username]))}",
        {
            'type': signal_type,
            'data': data,
            'sender': self.user.username
        }
    )

async def call_offer(self, event):
    """
    Send a WebRTC call offer to the recipient.
    """
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type': 'call_offer',
        'data': event['data'],
        'from': event['sender']
    }))

async def call_answer(self, event):
    """
    Send a WebRTC call answer to the recipient.
    """
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type': 'call_answer',
        'data': event['data'],
        'from': event['sender']
    }))

async def ice_candidate(self, event):
    """
    Send an ICE candidate to the recipient to assist in the WebRTC connection setup.
    """
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type': 'ice_candidate',
        'data': event['data'],
        'from': event['sender']
    }))

async def handle_key_exchange(self, data):
    """
    Handle the exchange of public keys for secure messaging.
    """
    recipient_username = data.get('to')
    public_key = data.get('publicKey')

    if public_key and recipient_username:
        await self.forward_public_key(recipient_username, public_key)

async def forward_public_key(self, recipient_username, public_key):
    """
    Forward the public key to the specified recipient.
    """
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        f"chat_{'_'.join(sorted([self.user.username, recipient_username]))}",
        {
            'type': 'public_key',
            'publicKey': public_key,
            'sender': self.user.username
        }
    )

async def public_key(self, event):
    """
    Deliver the public key to the WebSocket client.
    """
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type': 'public_key',
        'publicKey': event['publicKey'],
        'sender': event['sender']
    }))

async def handle_user_status(self, data):
    """
    Handle user status updates (online/offline).
    """
    recipient_username = data.get('to')
    status = data.get('status')

    if recipient_username and status:
        await self.forward_user_status(recipient_username, status)

async def forward_user_status(self, recipient_username, status):
    """
    Forward the user status to the specified recipient.
    """
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        f"chat_{'_'.join(sorted([self.user.username, recipient_username]))}",
        {
            'type': 'user_status',
            'status': status,
            'sender': self.user.username
        }
    )

async def user_status(self, event):
    """
    Deliver the user status update to the WebSocket client.
    """
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type': 'user_status',
        'status': event['status'],
        'sender': event['sender']
    }))

@database_sync_to_async
def update_user_status(self, online):
    """
    Update the user's online status in the database.
    """
    try:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(username=self.user.username)
        user_profile.online = online
        user_profile.save()
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        logger.error(f"User profile not found for {self.user.username}")

async def send_error(self, message):
    """
    Send an error message to the client.
    """
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'status': 'error',
        'message': message
    }))

this is my javascript code also,
 let sharedKey = null;
 let localECDHPrivateKey = null;
 let peerConnection = null;
 let localStream = null;

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
const socketProtocol = window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(`${socketProtocol}://${window.location.host}/ws/chat/${friendUsername}/`);

chatSocket.onopen = () => {
    console.log("WebSocket connection established.");
    securelyExchangeKeys();
    sendUserStatus('online'); // Notify the friend that the current user is online
};

chatSocket.onmessage = async function (event) {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);

    if (data.type === 'public_key') {
        console.log('Received public key from the friend.');
        await handlePublicKey(data);
    } else if (data.type === 'message') {
        await handleIncomingMessage(data.message, data.iv, data.sender);
    } else if (['call_offer', 'call_answer', 'ice_candidate'].includes(data.type)) {
        handleWebRTCSignal(data);
    } else if (data.type === 'user_status') {
        updateUserStatus(data.sender, data.status);
    } else {
        console.warn("Unhandled message type received:", data.type);
    }
};

chatSocket.onclose = () => {
    console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
    sendUserStatus('offline'); // Notify the friend that the current user is offline
};
chatSocket.onerror = (error) => console.error("WebSocket error:", error);

async function securelyExchangeKeys() {
    try {
        const keyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
            { name: 'ECDH', namedCurve: 'P-256' },
            true,
            ['deriveKey']
        );

        localECDHPrivateKey = keyPair.privateKey;
        const exportedPublicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey('raw', keyPair.publicKey);

        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: 'public_key',
            publicKey: Array.from(new Uint8Array(exportedPublicKey)),
            to: friendUsername
        }));

        console.log('Public key sent for secure key exchange.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during key generation or public key export:", error);
    }
}

async function handlePublicKey(data) {
    const publicKeyArray = new Uint8Array(data.publicKey);
    try {
        const importedPublicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
            'raw',
            publicKeyArray.buffer,
            { name: 'ECDH', namedCurve: 'P-256' },
            true,
            []
        );
        sharedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
            {
                name: 'ECDH',
                public: importedPublicKey
            },
            localECDHPrivateKey,
            {
                name: 'AES-GCM',
                length: 256
            },
            false,
            ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
        );
        console.log('Shared key successfully derived for secure messaging!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error deriving shared key:", error);
    }
}

async function handleIncomingMessage(encryptedMessage, iv, sender) {
    try {
        const decryptedMessage = await decryptMessage(sharedKey, encryptedMessage, iv);
        displayDecryptedMessage(sender || 'Friend', decryptedMessage);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Decryption error:", error);
    }
}

async function decryptMessage(sharedKey, encryptedMessage, iv) {
    try {
        const ivArray = new Uint8Array(iv);
        const ciphertext = new Uint8Array(encryptedMessage);
        const decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({ name: 'AES-GCM', iv: ivArray }, sharedKey, ciphertext);
        return new TextDecoder().decode(decrypted);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Decryption error:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

async function encryptMessage(sharedKey, message) {
    try {
        const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
        const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
        const ciphertext = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({ name: 'AES-GCM', iv }, sharedKey, encodedMessage);
        return { ciphertext: Array.from(new Uint8Array(ciphertext)), iv: Array.from(iv) };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Encryption error:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

function displayDecryptedMessage(sender, message) {
    const chatLog = document.getElementById('chat-log');
    const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
    messageElement.className = 'message';
    messageElement.innerHTML = `<strong>${sender}:</strong> ${message}`;
    chatLog.appendChild(messageElement);
}

const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button');
sendButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
    const message = messageInput ? messageInput.value.trim() : '';

    if (message !== '' && sharedKey) {
        try {
            const { ciphertext, iv } = await encryptMessage(sharedKey, message);
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'message', message: ciphertext, iv: iv, sender: currentUser, to: friendUsername }));
            messageInput.value = '';
            displayDecryptedMessage('You', message);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error encrypting message:", error);
        }
    } else {
        console.warn("Shared key is not ready or message is empty.");
    }
});

function sendUserStatus(status) {
    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'user_status', status: status, sender: currentUser }));
}

function updateUserStatus(username, status) {
    const statusElement = document.getElementById(`status-${username}`);
    if (statusElement) {
        statusElement.textContent = status === 'online' ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
        statusElement.classList.toggle('online', status === 'online');
        statusElement.classList.toggle('offline', status !== 'online');
    }
}

// WebRTC Signal Handling
async function handleWebRTCSignal(data) {
    if (!peerConnection) setupPeerConnection();

    switch (data.type) {
        case 'call_offer':
            await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.data));
            const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
            await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'call_answer', data: answer, to: friendUsername }));
            break;
        case 'call_answer':
            await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.data));
            break;
        case 'ice_candidate':
            if (data.data) {
                await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.data));
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.warn("Unhandled WebRTC signal:", data.type);
    }
}

async function startVideoCall() {
    setupPeerConnection();
    try {
        localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));
        displayLocalVideoStream(localStream);

        const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'call_offer', data: offer, to: friendUsername }));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error starting video call:", error);
    }
}

async function startVoiceCall() {
    setupPeerConnection();
    try {
        localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream));

        const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'call_offer', data: offer, to: friendUsername }));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error starting voice call:", error);
    }
}

function setupPeerConnection() {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] });

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'ice_candidate', data: event.candidate, to: friendUsername }));
        }
    };

    peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
        const remoteVideoElement = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
        if (remoteVideoElement) {
            remoteVideoElement.srcObject = event.streams[0];
            remoteVideoElement.play();
        }
    };
}

function displayLocalVideoStream(stream) {
    const localVideoElement = document.getElementById('localVideo');
    if (localVideoElement) {
        localVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
        localVideoElement.play();
    }
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    if (peerConnection) {
        peerConnection.close();
    }
});});

this is my chats.html also
{% extends "chat/Base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/chat/chats.css' %}">

<body class="dark-theme">

<!-- Chat Container -->
<div class="chat-container">
    <!-- Chat Header Section -->
    <div class="chat-header">
        <button class="back-button" 
     onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'chat:dashboard' %}'">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Friends
        </button>
        <div class="chat-user-info">
            <div class="user-avatar">
                <img src="https://api.dicebear.com/9.x/adventurer/png?seed={{ friend.name }}" alt="User Avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="user-details">
                <h3 id="friend-name">{{ friend.name }}</h3>
                <p class="user-status" id="status-{{ friend.username }}">Offline</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-actions">
            <button class="icon-button" id="voice-call" title="Voice Call">
                <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="icon-button" id="video-call" title="Video Call">
                <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Video Call Container -->
    <div class="video-container">
        <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
        <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
    </div>

    <!-- Chat Messages Section -->
    <div class="chat-messages" id="chat-log"></div>

    <!-- Message Input Section -->
    <div class="chat-input-section">
        <input type="text" id="message-input" placeholder="Type your message..." autocomplete="off">
        <button id="send-button" class="send-button"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    const friendUsername = "{{ friend.username }}"; // Assign friend's username to a JS variable
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/chat/chats.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}


what does javascript have to do with your question?

i have frontend as well, i dont know if it is my javascript causing the issue, will share if you want

have you checked for errors both in the backend (I wouldn't know where to look - have you tried some debugging output for the backend) and frontend (browser console)

i have tried all i know i still kept getting errors, my websocket seems to be connecting because i get no errors in my terminal, and my browser console no errors

no errors in my terminal, browser console no errors ... but i still kept getting errors ... where are these errors if they aren't on your backend or your frontend?

i added two users as friends i fix the add friend and delete parts since two users are already friend, user A and user B, they dont seems to be in the same room, user chat wont go through i get coudnt send message,between two user, i am not able to send messages i get 'Failed to send message. Please try again.'

so, still nothing in the browser console?

sorry i got errors in my console now
Error during message encryption: ReferenceError: sharedKey is not defined
 http://localhost:8000/static/js/chat/chats.js:89
chats.js:99:25
 http://localhost:8000/static/js/chat/chats.js:99

I thought you said there were no errors in the browser console? and yes, it does seem you use sharedKey in if (!sharedKey) statement and it's not defined anywhere

i dont understand what you mean, yes i used sharedkey

where is sharedKey declared (var or let)

thanks i will define it, it was not defined, yesterday i had no errors in my console, will define it then check

i declared the Sharedkey its sharing keys tho, but my chat not still working i will show the errors i am getting from console i will also share my code, i have troubleshoot many times still the same errors

please i have updated the javacript kindly check the errors i am getting i will send from both browsers

moziller console
::
Decryption error: DOMException: The operation failed for an operation-specific reason chats.js:108:21
decryptMessage http://localhost:8000/static/js/chat/chats.js:108
handleIncomingMessage http://localhost:8000/static/js/chat/chats.js:94
onmessage http://localhost:8000/static/js/chat/chats.js:24
(Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
 http://localhost:8000/static/js/chat/chats.js:17
(Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
 http://localhost:8000/static/js/chat/chats.js:7

chrome::
WebSocket connection established.
chats.js:57 Public key sent for secure key exchange.
chats.js:21 Received public key from the friend.
chats.js:86 Shared key successfully derived for secure messaging!
chats.js:108 Decryption error: OperationError
decryptMessage @ chats.js:108
await in decryptMessage
handleIncomingMessage @ chats.js:94
chatSocket.onmessage @ chats.js:24

when i type messages e.g, user A sent how are you, i get automatically
User A= how are you
User B = how are you,
this is vice versa, the users are not connecting nothing live between them evenn the video and calls is not fumctioning it will just acess camera or microphone
